# How to hide login form after login

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP. So I made a loginform for my website and where I'm having trouble hiding the form after the user logs in.. I want it to disappear after the user sucessfully logs in.
My code is the following,

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    $_SESSION['backurl'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>

<div class = "loginform">  
            <form name = "login" action = "login.php" method = "post" accept-charset = "utf-8"> 
                <?php
                     echo $_SESSION['username'];
                    //IF LOGADO TIRAR FORM. 
                ?>
                <ul>  
                    <li><label for = "usermail" class = "letralogin" >Email</label>  
                    <input type = "email" name = "usermail" placeholder = "yourname@email.com" required></li> 
                    <p>
                    <li><label for = "password" class = "letralogin">Password</label>  
                    <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "password" required></li> 
                    <p>                 
                    <input type = "submit" name = "login" value = "Login"></li>
                </ul>                   
            </form>
            </div>

            <div class = "divreg">
                <input type = "button" onclick = "location.href = 'registo.php';" value = "Registo" class = "buttreg"/>
            </div>
```

This is my code on login.php,

```
<?php
    include "connect.php";
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['usermail'];
        $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
        $sql = "select * from utilizador where email = '$username' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            echo 'OK';
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['backurl']);
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'wrong password';
            header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['backurl']);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: inicio.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you have saved that denotes if the user is logged in? Just the username session variable?

Comment: Where is your conditional checking if the user logged in?

Comment: I edited the post, hope that helps..

Comment: @reavstone: I have updated my answer adding session start function

Comment: What do you exactly want ? is your login part and your main part after logging in, in one page? Or they're in different pages?
and you want when the user logged in and typed your login page address in URL, the main page will be shown for him, correct?

Comment: The login form is in all pages, what I want is when the user logged in, the form disappears and the user stays in the same page he was.

Comment: Print your session after echo OK before header location. And use die(); after header location and for testing comment yur headers and print session array and chk is username set or not.

Comment: I did what you asked @devpro and this showed up on a blank page:

OKArray ( [backurl] => inicio.php [username] => )

Comment: This means username is not set did u add session_start in login.php file? Where your query located?

Comment: I edited my answer, see again and tell if you mean any other thing.

Comment: If I add session_start it gives me an error saying a session had already been started @devpro

Comment: All right last thing where u use echo OK just do it this.... remove ECHO OK... //header (). And use this  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['usermail'];   and after this refresh yur login form file... and share the result

Comment: Doesn't work @devpro it just takes me to the login.php page and shows it all blank

Comment: If page blank than print session I hope u r getting the username in session this time

Comment: Shows me this Array ( [backurl] => inicio.php [username] => ) @devpro

Comment: Also chk in private window

Comment: chk in private window? Sorry I didn't understood @devpro

Comment: Means private window of browser incognito

Comment: Shows me the same thing @devpro
Is there any other way we can talk, so its easier ?

Comment: Sidenote: I hope using `sha1` is only for testing purposes and not intended to go live. You should also add `exit;` after each header, otherwise you code may want to continue to execute. Another thing, make sure you did start the session and for all pages using sessions.

Comment: Its not going live, its just something i've been working on and playing around so I can understand a bit more. Yes I started the session for all pages @Fred -ii-

Comment: what I suggest you do is to wrap your form code inside an echo, assign a variable for the encapsulated form along with a session array, then echo it respectively. I.e.: `$form = '<form>...</form>';` etc. *done like dinner, and easy as pie* ;-)

Comment: By the way, you're outputting before header with echoes on top of your headers. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I mean. Probably why it's not working for you, given the answers below.

Comment: @Reavstone: yes we can, if you share your email on your Profile information.. remember don't share personal info here.... its not for social network...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check session in login file at top:

```
include "connect.php";

session_start();

    $_SESSION['backurl'] = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) )   {
       header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['backurl']);
}
```

If you have both separate files than you need to use session_start function in both files.

Comment: Thanks for the patience mate, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @reavstone can u check print_r ($_SESSION); AFTER FORM POST WHERE U ECHO OK after session creating

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want me to do, im new to this :/

Comment: @reavstone check your session is set properly? Like where u use    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; after this echo $_SESSION['username']; exit; ..... test this and let me knw the result

Comment: @Reavstone so tell me, why did you suddenly accept this answer and what made this all happen? probably the fact about me telling you about the header thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the username session variable is only set if the user is logged in, this would be what you want.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
HTML FORM CODE GOES HERE
<?php
}
?>
```

What this does is check if you have a username set, and if you don't it will display the HTML for the login form if you place it between the PHP tags. Additionally you could put a bit of JavaScript in there that hides your loginform div, which would also remove the login form from the page.

Comment: Didn't work, thanks for your help, I edited the post if you can, check it out.

Comment: *"What this does is check if you have a username set"* - `if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))` the `!` is the `NOT` operator. OP wants to check if it "is" set and hide the form if it is "set".

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your session is empty or not. Like this:

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['username']) {
       ?>
       <!--your login form-->
       <?php
} else {
       ?>
       main page.
       <?php
}
```

this is for the situation that you want when the user is not logged in no page be shown for him except Login part. Or if you want just hide login form after logging in, It will be like this:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['username']) {
       ?>
       <!--your login form-->
       <?php
}
?>
<!--main part details. -->
```

Comment: I already know when the user logs in or not, this piece of code:

<?php
                     echo $_SESSION['username'];
                    //IF LOGADO TIRAR FORM. 
                ?>

echoes the username, so I know if it logged or not.

Comment: Didn't work mate, it just hides the loginform from start, which means the user can't even login, its all gone.

Comment: @Reavstone sorry, one word has changed, `!empty` changed to `empty`.

Comment: Array ( [backurl] => inicio.php [username] => )
Shows me that on a blank login.php page @Majid Sadr

Answer (score 0):

*Foreword:*

You're presently outputting before header with the echos above your headers, and that alone will kill your code.

Either you echo **OR** header; you can't have both, not the way you are using them now.

- More on this here: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Here is a basic method and as I mentioned in comments, assign a variable to your form code, and encapsulated in quotes.

You can base yourself on the following skeleton/basic model and then take it from there.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

$_SESSION['user'] = "John";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>

<?php 


$form = '
            <form name = "login" action = "login.php" method = "post" accept-charset = "utf-8">

                <ul>  
                    <li><label for = "usermail" class = "letralogin" >Email</label>  
                    <input type = "email" name = "usermail" placeholder = "yourname@email.com" required></li> 
                    <p>
                    <li><label for = "password" class = "letralogin">Password</label>  
                    <input type = "password" name = "password" placeholder = "password" required></li> 
                    <p>                 
                    <input type = "submit" name = "login" value = "Login"></li>
                </ul>                   
            </form>

';


if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == 'John') {

    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['user'];

    }

    else{ 

    echo $form;

    }

?>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: seems like I wrote this for nothing.